# displaying unknown text when value does not exist in the list

Tags: angular

I am displaying a list in angular application and need to shown unknown string if the value does not exists

Is it the right way to do it

```
<h2>Jobs list</h2>
<table spacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer</th>
     
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let job of jobs">
         <td>{{job.customerName || 'unknown'}}</td>
          
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes! thats totally okay, its depends on your own way. you can also use `*ngIf` too. and `Turnary operator ? ''  : ''` too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ternary expression

```
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let job of jobs">
         <td>{{job.customerName ? job.customerName : 'unknown'}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```